# Approximate matches from Wikidata

Tags: sparql, wikidata, linked-data, wikidata-api

How do I call an API to query Wikidata for all matching results?

E.g., if I query "Washington", I'll get back, among others, the entries for "Washington D.C.", "George Washington" and "Washington Irving"?

Assuming this is possible, can I also do approximate queries? (e.g. get back the entry for "John Smith" when I query with "Smythe"?